# How to get the 'o' button?

Tags: vim-adventures

Hi guys I'm lost in level 11. I've searched both the Sky buffer and the ground buffer, and can't go any further.

This is the position on ground where I'm stuck:
[image]

This is the position on sky where I'm stuck:
[image]

It seems I need the O key to continue (which I haven't got).
Where can I find O key? Or maybe I can insert below/up the current line without O key?

Answer (score 1):

You can get **o** and **O** in the area below where you were stuck in the sky buffer:
[image: Vim-Adventures Level 11]
Access by editing the 'my dear Watson' line, which extends a path to the relevant sky island.  You need a blue key to open the door.

It's worth mentioning that you can also add lines with **p** and **P** if you have text in your register ('clipboard') and that text includes a **<NL>** (newline).  You can use **:reg** to check the contents of your registers.